# Jenkins kill all child processes

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job that runs a bash script.

In the bash script I perform effectively two actions, something like

```
java ApplicationA &
PID_A=$!
java ApplicationB
kill $PID_A
```

but if the job is manually aborted, the `ApplicationA` remains alive (as can be seen with a `ps -ef` on the node machine). I cannot use trapping and so on, because that won't work if jenkins sends a `9` signal (trapping doesn't work for `9`).

It would be ideal if this job could be configured to simply kill **all** processes that it spawns, how can I do that?

Comment: Is it ok if the job gets aborted after a certain time?

Comment: @Technext no, same as user cancel.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, when a user cancels a job, it's aborted only.

Comment: and what does that mean? I'd need something that works for timeouts and aborts (and possibly even if I simply forget to kill a child)

Comment: Check [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Aborting+a+build) link.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, by default, Jenkins has a feature called **[ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller)** which is responsible to make sure there are **no** processes left running after the job execution.

The link above explain how to disable that feature. Are you sure you **don't** have that disabled by mistake somehow?

**Edit:**
Following the comments by the author, based on the information about disabling **ProcessTreeKiller**, to achieve the inverse one must set the environment variable `BUILD_ID` to the build id of Jenkins job. This way, when **ProcessTreeKiller** looks through the running processes to kill, it will find this as well

`export BUILD_ID=$BUILD_ID`

You can also use the **[Build Result Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin)** plugin, configure a second job to clean up your applications, and configure it to monitor the first job for `ABORTED` state as a trigger.

Comment: I just checked our instance and it definitely doesn't have the disabling property set. I'm not sure the build result trigger would help because cleaning up afterwards is messy. I really need Jenkins to just do what it says it does with `ProcessTreeKiller`. Maybe I need to set some envvar or something.

Comment: I had a look at the child's environ using http://serverfault.com/questions/66363 and `BUILD_ID` does not appear to be set. :-/ looks like `&` loses that, so I believe the problem collapses to getting `&` to inherit environ.

Comment: I'm trying `export BUILD_ID=$BUILD_ID` on the first line to see if it fixes it.

Comment: yay! that worked. i'll answer my own question unless you do (because your link directed me to the answer)

Comment: I am on Jenkins 2.7.4 and `println(hudson.util.ProcessTree.enabled)` is set to `true`. Still my child processes are not going away when I ABORT the Jenkins job.