# Kill processes with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins script that executes a Windows application and runs some tests agains it.

With a normal (non-pipeline) Jenkins script, all processes were nicely cleaned up after job completion. It is my understanding that this is done by [ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller).

I try to convert the script to a pipeline script, which works fine, except now the processes are no longer killed.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402350/jenkins-kill-all-child-processes) question I see that BUILD_ID must be set in the processes. That is the case.

How do I get pipeline to kill the processes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to **execute batch command** after job completion.

For example, if your want to kill all ***chrome.exe*** processes, you can write your pipeline like this:

```
try {
  stage name: "something": 
} catch (err) {
  // handle errors here ? 
} finally {
  bat 'taskkill/F /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe"'
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing now. But it requires me to manually keep track of which processes I have started, with the risk of forgetting some, so it is far from perfect.