# Linux screen dissapears after Jenkins job is done

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have made a Jenkins pipeline for my Angular application.
This Angular application uses SSR, so you have to run it in the background.

Thus I decided to use a screen for this, here is my JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
      HOME = '.'
  }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        sh 'npm i'
        sh 'npm run build:ssr'
      }
    }

    stage('move') {
      steps {
        script {
          if (BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            sh 'rm -R /var/www/AngularJenkinsTest_Master/client || true'
            sh 'mkdir /var/www/AngularJenkinsTest_Master/client || true'
            sh 'cp -R $WORKSPACE/dist/AngularJenkinsTest/* /var/www/AngularJenkinsTest_Master/client'
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('publish') {
      steps {
        script {
          if (BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            sh 'screen -X -S AngularJenkinsTest_Master kill | true'
            sh 'screen -dmS AngularJenkinsTest_Master'
            sh 'screen -S AngularJenkinsTest_Master -X stuff "node /var/www/AngularJenkinsTest_Master/client/server/main.js\n"'
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

As you can see in "publish", I kill the screen (as it is running a node application), I then create a new screen and send a command to it.

I added a screen -ls to the end of it, and it did show that it existed, but when I go to my linux console.

```sh
jenkins@server:/root$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-jenkins.
```

This is the output that jenkins gives me:
[Jenkins Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dehix.jpg)

I am new to Jenkins, so maybe I am just being dumb, but is there any reason for this to happen?

Comment: A normal thing for Jenkins is to spawn a specific process for a build, launch everything inside and kill the process after the build finish. Check this wiki page: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build. This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/25402350/2689097 also has a valuable discussion and links.